# hive convert array<map<string, string>> to string

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, analytics

I have a column in hive table which type is `array<map<string, string>>`, I am struggling how to convert this column into `string` using hql?

I found post here [Convert Map<string,string> to just string in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788778/convert-mapstring-string-to-just-string-in-hive) to convert `map<string, string>` to `string`. However, I still failed to convert `array<map<string, string>>` to `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of the original answer you linked to, you can first explode the array into the individual maps using `posexplode` to maintain a positition column. Then you can use the method from the original post, but additionally group by the position column to convert each map to a string. Then you collect your maps into the final string. Here’s an example:

```sql
with test_data as (
select stack(2,
             1, array(map('m1key1', 'm1val1', 'm1key2', 'm1val2'), map('m2key1', 'm2val1', 'm2key2', 'm2val2')),
             2, array(map('m1key1', 'm1val1', 'm1key2', 'm1val2'), map('m2key1', 'm2val1', 'm2key2', 'm2val2'))
            ) as (id, arr_col)
),
map_data as (
select id, arr_col as original_arr, m.pos as map_num, m.val as map_col
  from test_data d
       lateral view posexplode(arr_col) m as pos, val
),
map_strs as (
select id, original_arr, map_num,
       concat('{',concat_ws(',',collect_set(concat(m.key,':', m.val))),'}') map_str
  from map_data d
       lateral view explode(map_col) m as key, val
 group by id, original_arr, map_num
 )
 select id, original_arr, concat('[', concat_ws(',', collect_set(map_str)), ']') as arr_str
 from map_strs
 group by id, original_arr;
```

Comment: nice work, but this is too complicated for me to use in our already complicated query.  Still looking for something that is an inline instead of an inline _view_ approach